# Fact measure security in SSAS

Tags: security, ssas, olap, fact, ssas-2012

I have a result fact which has a test result measure. It has the value of a result performed for a test. One of my requirement is to show the result to the users who have access but mask the result for example xxx to users who don't have the access to see the result measure.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is what i have decided to do. Add a calculated member of the measure which would detect the user name and depending upon their access would show the relevant result.

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement role level security in SSAS database which will show data only to the authorized users.